# Generated maven project has compiler error: ';' expected

Tags: java, maven-3

I am setting up a new maven java project with adapted pom.xml. The compiler gives an error on the generated maven java app. Why so?

I adapted pom.xml for compilation with java 1.8 and java 11, both are not working. Pom.xml is adapted for genearation of fatjar, which works when every java code is removed. Pom.xml is adapted for junit 4.11.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.no-ip.leder.gmr</groupId>
<artifactId>gmr_mvn</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>gmr_mvn</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <jdk.version>11</jdk.version>
    <jodatime.version>2.5</jodatime.version>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>${junit.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>gmr-digital-signature-mvn</finalName>
    <plugins>



        <!-- Set a compiler level -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Maven Assembly Plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- get all project dependencies -->
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <!-- MainClass in mainfest make a executable jar -->
                <archive>
                  <manifest>
                    <mainClass>org.no-ip.leder.gmr.Start</mainClass>
                  </manifest>
                </archive>

            </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>make-assembly</id>
                                    <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                <phase>package</phase> 
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>


</project>
```

Expected: Hello world in App.java from maven framework is compiled or any other java source.
Actual: `error: ';' expected`

```
package org.no-ip.leder.test;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }
}
```

Even unmodified pom.xml, with source and target 1.6, gives the error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project test_mvn: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /home/leder/Git/test_mvn/src/main/java/org/no-ip/leder/test/App.java:[1,15] ';' expected


<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.no-ip.leder.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test_mvn</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>test_mvn</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: The error seems to be in the source code, not in the `pom.xml`.

Comment: If the parser expects a `;`, then the error is probably not in the pom, but in the source code instead. Could you show us the code?

Comment: It's obvious that you forget the ';' sign somewhere in the java code. Check the line where the error occurs and add ';' at the end of the line.

Comment: Slow, slow, error is in the source generated by `mvn -B archetype:generate   -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes   -DgroupId=org.no-ip.leder.test   -DartifactId=test_mvn
`

Comment: Added App.java source code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error is due to the package name, package org.no-ip.leder.test;
The minus sign is an operator, convert that to an underscore and rename your folder accordingly.

Comment: Your answer is helpful despite the fact that is specified. Many times I had such issues.

Comment: Wow I just wasted 2 hours of my life trying to figure out why my application wouldn't compile because of a dash in the package name 0_o

Comment: If maven was an awesome tool it would stop you from entering invalid inputs.